# How to have pagination in this context for each foreach?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `UserController` that has the `index()` method that  get all congresses organzied by a user with "`$congresses = $user->congresses()->get();`". Then in the view I show, for example the draftCongresses, that are the congresses that have the stattus column as "D", like:

```
@foreach($congresses->filter(function ($item) { return $item->draftCongresses(); }) as $congress)
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <p class="font-size-xsm"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            {{$congress->start_date->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')}}</p>
        <h5 class="card-title">
            {{$congress->name}}</h5>
        <a href="{{route('congress.manage', ['id' => $congress->id])}}" class="btn btn-outline-primary font-size-sm">Panel</a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

I want to have a pagination for this results, to navigate between the draftCongresses. By default I just want to show 5 congresses then I want to have pagination to navigate between the other congresses.

Im not understanding how to use the laravel `paginate()` method because the congresses are get with "`$congresses = $user->congresses()->get();`" but then in the view there are different `foreach`, one foreach to show the `pastCongresses`, other to show the `publishedCongresses` and other to show the `draftCongresses`.

Do you know how to achieve a pagination for each foreach in this scenario? Because there is only one route that returns all congresses organized by the user to the view and then each foreach shows the necessary results in each tab.

// user controller that returns all congresses organized by the auth user to the view

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        $user = Auth::user();

        $congresses = $user->congresses()->get();

        return view('users.index', compact('user','registrations', 'congresses', $congresses));
    }
}
```

Congress Model:

```
    class Congress extends Model
    {
        public function pastCongresses(): bool
    {
        return $this->end_date < now();
    }

    public function draftCongresses(): bool
    {
        return $this->status == 'D';
    }

    public function publishedCongresses(): bool
    {
        return $this->status == 'P';
    }
    }
```

Route to this view:

```
 Route::get('/user/profile', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@index',
        'as'   =>'user.index'
    ]);
```

// View that have the tabs to show the pastCongresses, the draftCongresses and the publishedCongresses.

```
<div class="tab-pane clearfix fade" id="myCongresses" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
    <div class="d-flex mb-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active border" href="#draftCongresses" data-toggle="tab"
                   role="tab">Draft congresses</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link border" href="#publishedCongresses" data-toggle="tab"
                   role="tab">Published</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link border" href="#pastCongresses" data-toggle="tab"
                   role="tab">Past Congresses</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content bg-white" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade active show clearfix" id="draftCongresses" role="tabpanel"
             aria-labelledby="home-tab">
            <ul class="list-group">
                @foreach($congresses->filter(function ($item) { return $item->draftCongresses(); }) as $congress)
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <p class="font-size-xsm"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            {{$congress->start_date->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')}}</p>
                        <h5 class="card-title">
                            {{$congress->name}}</h5>
                        <a href="{{route('congress.manage', ['id' => $congress->id])}}" class="btn btn-outline-primary font-size-sm">Panel</a>
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
            <!-- Pagination div static for now-->
            <div class="text-center mt-3">
                <div class="col">
                    <nav aria-label="...">
                        <ul class="pagination d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <li class="page-item disabled">
                                <span class="page-link">Previous</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                            <li class="page-item active">
                                <span class="page-link">2</span>
                                  <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade show clearfix" id="publishedCongresses" role="tabpanel"
             aria-labelledby="home-tab">
            <ul class="list-group">
                @foreach($congresses->filter(function ($item) { return $item->publishedCongresses(); }) as $congress)

                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <p class="font-size-xsm"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            {{$congress->start_date->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')}}</p>
                        <h5 class="card-title">
                            {{$congress->name}}</h5>
                        <a href="{{route('congress.manage', ['id' => $congress->id])}}" class="btn btn-outline-primary font-size-sm">Panel</a>
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>

            <!-- Pagination div static for now-->

            <div class="text-center mt-3">
                <div class="col">
                    <nav aria-label="...">
                        <ul class="pagination d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <li class="page-item disabled">
                                <span class="page-link">Previous</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                            <li class="page-item active">
                                <span class="page-link">2</span>
                                  <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade show clearfix" id="pastCongresses" role="tabpanel"
             aria-labelledby="home-tab">
            <ul class="list-group">
                @foreach($congresses->filter(function ($item) { return $item->pastCongresses(); }) as $congress)

                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <p class="font-size-xsm"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            {{$congress->start_date->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')}}</p>
                        <h5 class="card-title">
                            {{$congress->name}}</h5>
                        <a href="{{route('congress.manage', ['id' => $congress->id])}}" class="btn btn-outline-primary font-size-sm">Panel</a>
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>

            <!-- Pagination div static for now-->

            <div class="text-center mt-3">
                <div class="col">
                    <nav aria-label="...">
                        <ul class="pagination d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <li class="page-item disabled">
                                <span class="page-link">Previous</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                            <li class="page-item active">
                                <span class="page-link">2</span>
                                  <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First if you want to use pagination change you query 
from this:

```
$congresses = $user->congresses()->get();
```

into this:

```
$congresses = $user->congresses()->paginate(PAGE_SIZE);
```

Read the brief documentation about pagination [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination).

Second, it's not a good idea to apply another filter to pagination result specially inside a view; It's against MVC design pattern and you can't consider it as a best practice.

You could apply it in your controller and pass the result to your view:

```
$draftCongresses = $user->congresses()->where('status', 'D')->paginate(PAGE_SIZE)
```

Now you can use the `$draftCongress` in the `foreach` loop and access the `$draftCongress->links()`.

Comment: Thanks, but like that do you know how to use the "        //$pastCongresses = $user->congresses()->where('end_date', < now())->paginate(5);? 
"

Comment: And can you show how the view should stay? To accomplish that best practice? Is just use "                                        @foreach($draftCongresses as $draftCongress)
"?

Comment: @joW Please take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to set it up as three separate queries.  Also, placing the logical check inside of a model method is a little awkward.  I think a query-scope might suit you better there.  Try setting up your Model like this:

```
class Congress extends Model
{
    public function scopePastCongresses($query)
    {
        return $query->where('end_date', '<' now());
    }

    public function scopeDraftCongresses($query)
    {
        return $query->where('status', 'D');
    }

    public function scopePublishedCongresses($query)
    {
        return $query->where('status', 'P');
    }
}
```

Next your Controller:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    protected $defaultPageLimit = 5;

    public function index(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        $pageLimit = $request->input('page_limit', $this->defaultPageLimit);

        $user = $request->user();
        $congresses = $user->congresses();
        $past = $congresses->past()->paginate($pageLimit);
        $draft = $congresses->draft()->paginate($pageLimit);
        $published = $congresses->published()->paginate($pageLimit);

        $congresses = compact('past', 'draft', 'published');

        return view('users.index', compact('user', 'registrations', 'congresses'));
    }
}
```

And finally your View:

```
@foreach($congresses['draft'] as $congress)
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <p class="font-size-xsm"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            {{$congress->start_date->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')}}</p>
        <h5 class="card-title">
            {{$congress->name}}</h5>
        <a href="{{route('congress.manage', ['id' => $congress->id])}}" class="btn btn-outline-primary font-size-sm">Panel</a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

If your intent though, is to just grab 5-page chunks and separate-out the results afterwards, you can ignore the query-scope idea, and set your Controller up like this instead:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    protected $defaultPageLimit = 5;

    public function index(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        $pageLimit = $request->input('page_limit', $this->defaultPageLimit);

        $user = $request->user();
        $congresses = $user->congresses()->paginate($pageLimit);
        $past = $congresses->filter(function ($congress) {
            return ($congress->end_date < now());
        });
        //Note, this is NOT an SQL query-where.  The results of the query above come back as an Eloquent\Collection object, a child of Support\Collection, which itself has its own 'where()' method separate from Eloquent, that just acts like a filter.
        $draft = $congresses->where('status', 'D');
        $published = $congresses->where('status', 'P');

        $congresses = compact('past', 'draft', 'published');

        return view('users.index', compact('user', 'registrations', 'congresses'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but then do you know how to get the pagination working? With " {{$congresses->links()}}" after each foreach it appears "Call to a member function links() on array"

Comment: At that point, `$congresses` is an array with three elements.  Each one being a different filtered subset, in the form of a Collection.  You'd have to specify the key of the one you want, or merge them first.